# MS bot | QnAmaker- how to Display the answers in ordered /bulleted format

Tags: c#, botframework, direct-line-botframework, azure-qna-maker

I'm using QnAMaker in the back end for my chat bot, which is running in direct line bot channel.
I want to display some answers in bulleted / numbered format.

I tried some methods mentioned in [some websites including this one.](https://thewebspark.com/2018/02/18/conversational-text-formatting-in-microsoft-bot-framework/)

like this

> "Hi, Below is my list\n\n"+ "* Item 1\n\n"+ "* Item 2\n\n"+ "Item 1
> ");

but nothing worked for me,
[image]

**Also, I want to know if its possible to display table of data / or any HTML data as bot's reply.**

If someone has any solution for this issue, please let me know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems you are trying to format your text in `Azure Bot Framework`. After having look on your code, I got to know, you are almost there, but approach was not correct.

You could try following way

***Unordered list :***

```cs
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Hi, Below is my unordered list  " + Environment.NewLine+ " 1. Item 1\r2. **Bold Item 2**\r3. **" + YourDynamicObject + "**"), cancellationToken);
```

***Ordered list :***

```cs
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Hi, Below is my ordered list " + Environment.NewLine+ " - Item 1\r- **Bold Item 2**\r- [Hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9663070/md-farid-uddin-kiron) 3"), cancellationToken);
```

See the screen shot below:

[image]

***How Would You Do It:***

I have already given you code example above, additionally keep in mind the space between the syntax for example when you would make `hyperlink` you have to follow it's structure like `[title](URL)` but if you put space after title angle bracket `[]` it won't work as expected, also for bold **Bold** it shouldn't contain any space before and after. Same things happened with  your code.

Another issue is `new line` you could use `\n\n` even `Environment.NewLine`

***I want to know if its possible to display table of data / or any HTML data as bot's reply?***

> The answer is `NO` unfortunately you cannot display table data on bot at this moment.
>   But it support few [`HTML Tag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format#html-formatting-for-connector-cards)  hope you got your answer.

If you would like to know more about `Azure Bot Card Formatting` you could refer [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format#html-formatting-for-connector-cards)

Hope it would help and feel free to ask when you would encounter any question in mind.

Comment: For this question I have given you the resolution as you haven't share your code here. So asked another question with your code and problem you encounter

Comment: Farid, its working solution thank you so much for helping me

Comment: By the way, I have also tested with `QnA Maker` which also worked.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually possible to format a message in table format using markdown. I'm not sure it will work with QnA Maker, and I'm almost positive it won't work for every channel, but for standard webchat I have been able to send table-formatted messages as follows:

```js
var ticketTable = `|Ticket# |Status |Summary|\n|:---|:---|:---|`;
for (var i = 0; i < ticketArray.length; i++) {
    ticketData = await RemedyServiceHelper.getTicketData(ticketArray[i]);
    ticketTable += `\n|${ticketData.ticketNumber}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|${ticketData.status}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|${ticketData.summary}|`;
}
await step.context.sendActivity(`Here is the current status of your requests:`);
await step.context.sendActivity(ticketTable);
```

I would probably not recommend this though because there is no guarantee it will appear properly through all channels. I've started using Carousels instead to display items in a similar way. For example:

```js
                var lineData = [];
                for (var idx = 0; idx < lineItemDetails.lineDetail.length; idx++) {
                    var title = `${lineItemDetails.orderNumber}  \r\n Line ${lineItemDetails.lineDetail[idx].lineNumber}`;
                    var message = `Product ID: ${lineItemDetails.product}  \r\n Status: ${lineItemDetails.lineDetail[idx].lineStatus}  \r\n Quantity: ${lineItemDetails.lineDetail[idx].quantity}  \r\n Date: ${lineItemDetails.lineDetail[idx].nextDate}  \r\n Carrier: ${lineItemDetails.lineDetail[idx].scacCode}  \r\n Tracking: ${lineItemDetails.lineDetail[idx].trackingNumber}`;
                    var lineCard = CardFactory.heroCard(title, message);
                    lineData.push(lineCard);
                }
                await step.context.sendActivity(`I found multiple lines or releases. Please scroll through the cards below to see each result.`);
                await step.context.sendActivity(MessageFactory.carousel(lineData));
```

I used Hero Cards to build this, though you could format the cards however you wanted using Adaptive Cards. While these won't *appear* the same in all channels, they should *work* in all channels, so safer than using table markdown or HTML.

Comment: thanks for your solution, it may be helping for building a table kind of answer via code , however my requirement is to display a tabular from QnAmaker

Comment: I haven't tried the same syntax directly in QnA Maker, it may work?

Comment: I've tried the same way in QnAMaker  but it doesn't help.